# How to access a logo or image under a tpl file using CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to access a logo or image under a tpl file ?

For example

```
<?php echo $view->logo;  ?> calling from the home page showing me the logo
```

but under menu.tpl file this same not showing any result. Below is the exception i am getting

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$logo in /var/www/yoursite.com/application/views/default/application/client/countyx/menu_client.tpl on line: 12

File: /var/www/yoursite.com/application/views/default/application/client/countyx/menu_client.tpl, on line 12, Error->error_handler()
File: /var/www/yoursite.com/system/view.php, on line 149, Undefined->require()
File: /var/www/yoursite.com/application/controllers/wrapper_client.php, on line 81, View->render()
File: Undefined, on line Undefined, Wrapper_clientController->indexAction()
File: /var/www/yoursite.com/system/layout.php, on line 236, ReflectionMethod->invoke()
File: /var/www/yoursite.com/system/response.php, on line 107, Layout->add_wrapper()
File: /var/www/yoursite.com/default.php, on line 194, Response->output()
Logged Data:
    SELECT id, menu_title AS title, parent_id, friendly_url, external, highlight FROM prefix_pages WHERE owner_id = '408' AND active = '1' AND menu = '1' ORDER BY sort_id LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: can you share the full code

Comment: Plz. Check Line number 12 https://pastebin.com/sN8SejwM

Comment: Can you do one thing set your logo image to data variable and then pass that data variable to view.insted of <?php echo $view->logo; ?>